# nodejs installation in redhat AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redhat

From last 4 hours I am trying to install nodejs, I have a linux machine.

```
 **$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.4 (Tikanga)**
```

I have downloaded the nodeJs setup and when I run the (./configure) command its showing error.

```
$ ./configure 
  File "./configure", line 511
    o['default_configuration'] = 'Debug' if options.debug else 'Release'
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RHEL 5 has old Python version.

Run `python --version`. You need at least Python 2.7 for that install script to work, so update your Python first.

Comment: Yes, I have updated now, 
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12

-----------------------------
still getting same problem
$ sudo yum -y install nodejs
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package nodejs available.
Nothing to do

Comment: after that I follow below steps and its working now..
wget --no-check-certificate https://nodejs.org/dist/v4.2.1/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ cd /usr/local/
$sudo tar --strip-components 1 -xzf /home/hybris/nodeJs/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
$ node -v
v4.2.1


Thanks ...

Answer (score 0):

**For Node.js v4 LTS Argon:**

curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | bash -

**For Node.js v6:**

curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -

**For Node.js 0.10:**

curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -

**and next as root:**

yum install epel-release

yum -y install nodejs

Comment: I already done all googling, getting below error.
$ yum -y install nodejs
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
No package nodejs available.
Nothing to do

Comment: how can I do this, please suggest.

Comment: do this.. sudo yum install epel-release

Comment: $ sudo yum install epel-release
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Install Process
Package epel-release-5-4.noarch already installed and latest version
Nothing to do


**I have done all the thing which I found in google.